# Number of paths moving diagonally right that never cross the x axis

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose we start at the origin and at each step move in the direction $(1, 1)$ or $(1, -1)$, for a total of $n$ steps, without ever crossing the x axis. That is, once we take the first step, we must stay on that side of the x axis, though we may touch the x axis as many times as we want. How many possible paths are there? I've tried drawing it out and looking for a pattern, but I haven't quite gotten there yet. I've observed that this is the same as twice the number of binary strings of length $n$ where every prefix substring has at least as many 1's as 0's

Comment: This is a version of the classical "ballot problem" (http://webspace.ship.edu/msrenault/ballotproblem/Four%20Proofs%20of%20the%20Ballot%20Theorem.pdf)